# How to get elements of a sublist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

I've already googled but couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

I want to save all the numbers in the first list: "list".

If the numbers are divisible by 2, I also want to save them in the second list: "list2"

My problems are:

1. Which parameters should the sublist get? I dont think (list.subList (0, list.size ()) are correct;)
2. How can I get the elements of the sublist "list2" in my print () method?

I can only pass the first list as parameter

Thanks for your help!

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(0, list.size()));

    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
            list2.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    print(list);

}

private static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    for (Integer integer : list) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use streams: `List<Integer> list2 = list1.stream().filter(value -> value % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: You can call the print method twice with your two different list. One the main list and second time the sublist which is divisible by 2. What problem you face in that approach ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
list.add(10);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
       list2.add(list.get(i));
    }
}

print(list, list2);



private static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {

    for (Integer integer : list) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
    System.out.println("----sublist----");
    for (Integer integer : list2) {
       System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

---

```
print(list);
print(list2);

private static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    for (Integer integer : list) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

}
```

---

```
print(list);
    
    private static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
            if(integer%2==0){
               System.out.println("sub list----"+integer);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thax :) 
I can only pass the first list as parameter. 

Is there a way to access the sublist without passing the second list as a parameter?

Comment: your sublist contains only elements which can be divisible by 2. you can arrive that based on the first list

Comment: I have added three suggestion. Take a look at third

Answer (score 1):

Declare the List globally. And send the first list as the parameter. Print the sublist in the print method.

```
public class Main {

static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(0, list.size()));

public static void main(String[] args) {

    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
            list2.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("------------------Orginal List------------------");
    print(list);
    
}

private static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (Integer integer : list) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
    
    System.out.println("------------------Sub List------------------");
    
    for (Integer integer : list2) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
------------------Original List------------------                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                                                                           
1                                                                                                                                                           
4                                                                                                                                                           
5                                                                                                                                                           
10                                                                                                                                                          
------------------Sub List------------------                                                                                                                
2                                                                                                                                                           
4                                                                                                                                                           
10
```

Comment: Hi Som, thank you!
Is this line correct?: static ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(0, list.size()));

Can I pass this parameter to a sublist?

Comment: @alvira  Yes you can pass this ... My code is tested. Otherwise it would have thrown compilation errors if the statement was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can use java Streams to achieve this. It's cleaner and easier to work with, and also less code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        list.add(2);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(10);
        
        list2 = list.stream()
            .filter( number -> number%2==0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
        
        for(int number : list2) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the scope of sub list. So print() can assess.

```
public class Test {

    static ArrayList<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         list.add(2);
            list.add(1);
            list.add(4);
            list.add(5);
            list.add(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
                    sublist.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }

            print(list);

        }

        private static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

            for (Integer integer : list) {
                if(sublist.contains(integer))
                System.out.println(integer);
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one uses Java 8 or later, I would suggest using the [streaming API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
public static List<Integer> extractEvens(final List<Integer> numbers) {
    return numbers.stream()
        .filter(value -> value % 2 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/otv2Y4)